# Building Link/URL Shortener, question about approach

Tags: php, redirect

I am building a link shortener. So far I have been creating a new folder for each shortened link, with an index page in the folder with a redirect. However with this approach I could end up with many thousands of folders. Seems like this is not efficient. I need to consider growth in this. Eventually could end up with a million folders.

I can't think of another way to do this? Wondering if anyone has a suggestion?
How do big companies like Bitly manage that?

Comment: You should look into using databases (to store the data), front controller pattern (to have one file for all requests) and routers (to create "virtual" URL patterns that doesn't necessarily correspond to the filesystem). I would suggest looking into one of the many tried and tested PHP frameworks, which all have/uses those things. The question is too unfocused/broad for a more precise answer.

Comment: Yep, currently I have been testing just using the 404 page. One file that way - and it pulls the url data from the database. Still, somehow seems like an odd approach

Comment: The front controller pattern isn't about the 404 page. It's a way to redirect all requests to non-existing resources (through rewrite rules) to your index.php. There you can set up a router with all application routes (and have wild card params for dynamic contents). This is the absolutely most common way of setting things up in a modern application.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a direction to go in. I had not considered that approach. Appreciated!